# Is it possible to get a 'closed form' for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k b_{n-k}$?

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, closed-form, laurent-series

This came up when trying to divide series, or rather, express $\frac1{f(x)}$ as a series, knowing that $f(x)$ has a zero of order one at $x=0$, and knowing the Taylor series for $f(x)$  (that is knowing the $b_i$ 's).

I write $$1=\frac1{f(x)}f(x) = (\frac{r}{x}+a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...)(b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3+...)$$

And comparing coefficients I get $r= \frac{1}{b_1}$ and more importantly, the equations:

$$0=b_{n+1}r + \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k b_{n-k}.$$

Is there a closed form for this recursion, i.e. is it possible to extract $a_n = ...$ from this? In the particular case I'm looking at, $b_n = \frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: This is known as the convolution $a\ast b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know $f$ has a zero of order $1$ you can write it as $$f(x)=x\left(a_1+a_2x+a_3x^2+\ldots\right),$$
with $a_1\neq0$.

Then $\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{a_1+a_2x+a_3x^2+\ldots}$.

To compute the series of $\frac{1}{a_1+a_2x+a_3x^2+\ldots}$ just apply long division of $1$ divided by $a_1+a_2x+a_3x^2+...$. This is an algorithm that allows you to compute, term by term, the series if the quotient.

If we have more information on $f$ other methods could be applied. For $f$ a rational function there is a much better method.

Comment: The trouble with long division is that it's impossible to get a formula for all the coefficients. I'm trying to find the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{e^x -1}$ at zero, and my idea was to invert it, but this doesn't let me write it down explicitly.

Comment: Yes, some functions don't have a nice formula in terms of simpler functions. When you have a concrete problem it is better to give it explicitly, instead of making unnecessary generalizations. You don't want to invert every series (for which there is nothing much better than recursive formulas). For $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ you can express the coefficients, but you may need to use special functions. In this case, [Bernoulli's numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function].